# express.js does not async call the same router callback?

Tags: node.js, express

When '/a' is called, '/b' can be executed immediately. But If I invokes another '/a', the second one waits for the first one ending. How can I make '/a' really async called?

code:

```
app.get '/a', (req, res, next) ->
  f = ->
    res.send 'a' 
    console.log 'end', new Date()
  console.log 'sleep', new Date()
  setTimeout f, 10000

app.get '/b', (req, res, next) ->
  res.send 'b'
```

output:

```
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
sleep Sun Oct 14 2012 12:37:52 GMT+0800 (SGT)
GET /b 200 9ms - 1
end Sun Oct 14 2012 12:38:02 GMT+0800 (SGT)
GET /a 200 10022ms - 1
sleep Sun Oct 14 2012 12:38:02 GMT+0800 (SGT)
end Sun Oct 14 2012 12:38:12 GMT+0800 (SGT)
GET /a 200 10005ms - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the reason, it is because I ran two '/a' on the same browser. I just tried to run one in chromium, and the other one in firefox, they were handled asyncly. Looks interesting.

Comment: Right, since you don't do the `res.send` until after the sleep, you'll hang a browser since it is waiting for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're seeing.  When I run the test, I get the expected results - the requests to `\a` are handled asynchronously.  If you try the following code and execute it with `DEBUG=* node app.js` do you get the same results that I do?

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.get('/a', function (req, res, next) {
  var f = function () {
    res.send('a');
    console.log('end', new Date());
  };

  console.log('sleep', new Date());
  setTimeout(f, 10000);
});

app.get('/b', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('b');
});

app.listen(4000);
```

Here is the output from running two requests to `\a` and a request to `\b` while the first two are sleeping.

```
  express:router dispatching GET /a (/a) +52s    // first call to \a
  express:router matched get /a +1ms
sleep Sat Oct 13 2012 21:59:42 GMT-0700 (PDT)     
  connect:dispatcher query +530ms
  connect:dispatcher expressInit +1ms
  connect:dispatcher router +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /a (/a) +530ms  // second call to \a in parallel
  express:router matched get /a +0ms
sleep Sat Oct 13 2012 21:59:42 GMT-0700 (PDT)
  connect:dispatcher query +874ms
  connect:dispatcher expressInit +0ms
  connect:dispatcher router +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /b (/b) +874ms  // call to \b handled immediately
  express:router matched get /b +0ms
end Sat Oct 13 2012 21:59:52 GMT-0700 (PDT)   // first call to \a ends
end Sat Oct 13 2012 21:59:52 GMT-0700 (PDT)   // second call ends at same time
```

You can see that the request to `\b` finishes immediately and then the two requests to `\a` both finish after 10s, meaning that they were, in fact, handled in parallel (as is expected).

Answer (score 0):

Bill, I got different result with your code. I ran these via browser. I am using Express 3 on Linux with only one core.

```
  express:application booting in development mode +0ms
  connect:dispatcher use / query +0ms
  connect:dispatcher use / expressInit +0ms
  connect:dispatcher use / router +2ms
  express:router defined get /a +0ms
  express:router defined get /b +1ms
  connect:dispatcher query +12s
  connect:dispatcher expressInit +2ms
  connect:dispatcher router +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /a (/a) +12s
  express:router matched get /a +0ms
sleep Sun Oct 14 2012 13:20:37 GMT+0800 (SGT)
  connect:dispatcher query +3s
  connect:dispatcher expressInit +0ms
  connect:dispatcher router +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /b (/b) +3s
  express:router matched get /b +1ms
end Sun Oct 14 2012 13:20:47 GMT+0800 (SGT)
  connect:dispatcher query +6s
  connect:dispatcher expressInit +0ms
  connect:dispatcher router +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /a (/a) +6s
  express:router matched get /a +0ms
sleep Sun Oct 14 2012 13:20:47 GMT+0800 (SGT)
end Sun Oct 14 2012 13:20:57 GMT+0800 (SGT)
```